# Почему не работает innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5

Есть элемент <span></span> в который нужно засунуть то, что выдаст функция.
Но почему span не меняет свой inner.
Вот пример:

```js
function foo(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('number').textContent;
  elem = parseInt(elem);
  elem = elem + 5;
  elem.innerHTML = elem;
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="number">10</span>
  <button onclick = "foo()">Result</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Подскажите, почему не меняется то число в самом HTML документе?

Comment: `elem` в вашем коде — это число. У числа не существует никакого innerHTML

Comment: А каким образом можно это число туда поместить?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что вы в `elem` складываете не элемент, выбранный по идентификатору, а его текст.

```js
function foo() {
  let elem = document.getElementById('number');
  let elemNumber = parseInt(elem.textContent);
  elemNumber += 5;
  elem.innerHTML = elemNumber;
  console.log(elemNumber);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="number">10</span>
  <button onclick = "foo()">Result</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что присваивается значение копии тега, а не ему самому. Да и то, не тега, а контента.

```js
function foo(){
  var elem = document.getElementById('number').textContent;
  elem = parseInt(elem);
  elem = elem + 5;
  elem.innerHTML = elem;
  document.getElementById('number').innerHTML = elem;
  console.log(elem);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <span id="number">10</span>
  <button onclick = "foo()">Result</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 function foo(){
    var elem = document.getElementById('number').textContent;
    elem = parseInt(elem);
    elem = elem + 5;
    console.log(elem);
    return elem = elem.innerHTML
}
```